# How to redirect specific range of ports to port 80 in node.js

Tags: apache2, nodejs

When I use the below command, I am able to redirect from port 3000 to port 80, but I need to redirect to port 80 when a request is for any other port.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are redirecting traffic that arrives on eth0 via tcp and arrives at port 80(!) to port 3000(!), so it is the other way around! To forward all traffic to port 3000, just remove the --dport 80 (the --dport 80 option means: apply this rule only to packets that are sent to port 80):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

The above command describes a rule that says: all traffic on eth0 (your network card) that uses the tcp protocol (-p(rotocol) tcp) shall be redirected (-j REDIRECT) to port 3000.

To forward all traffic to port 80 (like you originally asked, but the other way around than in your example, just remove the 3000 and insert 80 instead.